# Custom ListView Adapter displays no results

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I'm working with a ListFragment and have prepared a custom ListView adapter by extending from the BaseAdapter, I've called the method to set the adapter in the Fragment but the Listview is not displaying anything.
Below is my Custom adapter and ListFragment classes:

The Adapter:

```
package adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.sarham.kabs.fruity.R;

/**
 * Created by Kabunyi Wanja on 22/03/2015.
 */
public class CategoriesListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context context;

    public CategoriesListAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        CategoryViewHolder categoryViewHolder;
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categories_list_custom_layout, parent, false);

            categoryViewHolder = new CategoryViewHolder();
            categoryViewHolder.category = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_categories);
            convertView.setTag(categoryViewHolder);
        }
        else{
            categoryViewHolder = (CategoryViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        categoryViewHolder.category.setText("Category");
        //on testing, the below line never executes
        Log.d("ADAPTER", "Textview updated");

        return convertView;
    }
    //ViewHolder class
    public static class CategoryViewHolder{
        TextView category;
    }
}
```

The LIstFragment:

```
package com.sarham.kabs.fruity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import adapters.CategoriesListAdapter;

/**
 * Created by Kabunyi Wanja on 22/03/2015.
 */
public class CategoriesFragment extends ListFragment {
    private ListView categoriesListView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categories_fragment, container, false);
        categoriesListView = (ListView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        setCategoriesListAdapter();
        Log.d("ADAPTER: ", "Adapter has been set for listview");

        return v;
    }
    //set adapter to categoriesListView
    public void setCategoriesListAdapter(){
        categoriesListView.setAdapter(new CategoriesListAdapter(getActivity()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `getCount()` method returns zero.  This will cause the ListView to act as though there is no data.

Answer (score 0):

From your adapter:

```
public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please explain **why** this is a problem for the OP and what he should do to fix it. Then it will be an answer.

Comment: I thought it is self-explanatory. This method should return count of views (rows) in list. Usually something like `return options.size` or `return options.length`. But in OP case, he is using CategoryViewHolder class, and reusing some views (?), so he should figure out how many views app should show.